# PIL replacing colour without affecting edges

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a relatively complex image drawn with black lines that I want to change the background colour from white to a random colour.

Using PIL I am replacing all non-black pixels with the colour:

```
  pixels = output.getdata()
  newPixels = []

  for pixel in pixels:
    if pixel[0] != 0 and pixel[1] != 0 and pixel[2] != 0:
      newPixels.append(color)
    else:
      newPixels.append(pixel)

  output.putdata(newPixels)
```

This makes the lines all jagged as I replace the edge smoothing not completely black pixels as well. Any solutions?

Comment: Could you show us the image? If it's purely greyscale, I have an idea.

Comment: Edge detect the image, then avoid changing pixels in those areas.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to retain pure black and replace pure white. Everything else needs to be blended.

Here's the simplest way of doing the blend:

```
newPixels.append([pixel[i] * color[i] // 255 for i in (0,1,2)])
```